# What is the difference between repr(C) and repr(rust)?

Tags: rust

I am currently writing a Vulkan renderer and I just realized that I should only accept types that are `repr(C)`, but as far as I know there is no way to actually check that at compile time.

```
struct Vertex {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    b: Box<f32>
}

#[repr(C)]
struct Vertex2 {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    b: Box<f32>
}

fn to_bytes<T>(t: &T) -> &[u8]{
    let p: *const T = t;
    let p = p as *const u8;
    unsafe{
        std::slice::from_raw_parts(p, std::mem::size_of::<T>())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = Vertex{x: 42.0, y: 0.0, b: Box::new(42.0)};
    let v2 = Vertex2{x: 42.0, y: 0.0, b: Box::new(42.0)};
    println!("{:?}", to_bytes(&v));
    println!("{:?}", to_bytes(&v2));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5c29b9a791c535973620c65c2be0b6fe&version=stable&backtrace=0)

After a few tries, I could finally see a difference between `repr(c)` and `repr(rust)` but only when I used a `Box`.

What is the difference between `repr(C)` and `repr(rust)`? Can I assume that if a type only contains other POD types, then the layout will be the same as in C?

Example:

```
let slice = base.device
    .map_memory::<Vertex>(vertex_input_buffer_memory,
                          0,
                          vertex_input_buffer_info.size,
                          vk::MemoryMapFlags::empty())
    .unwrap();
slice.copy_from_slice(&vertices);
```

[Source](https://github.com/MaikKlein/ash/blob/master/examples/src/bin/triangle.rs#L183)

I am filling a buffer that I hand to Vulkan, so I assume that the layout here probably matters.

Comment: "*I should only accept types that are `repr(C)`*"  -> could you clarify that? You do accept generic types in some of your methods and need those to be `repr(C)`? Why?

Comment: I don't think there is any guarantee that Rust will use the same representation for data as C does.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt I am not completely sure what you mean, but I added an example in my question. Surely `Vertex` here should match the C layout that the shader is going to use? I am not quite sure if `#[repr(C)]` will also result in a different size because of different packing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference you see in the output of your program is not due to memory layout. `Box<T>` heap allocates and stores a pointer to the heap contents, so what you are printing is the pointer. As `Box<T>` doesn't perform any interning/object pooling, the two addresses are of course different. What's probably a bit confusing is that the addresses are so close to each other. I *guess* this has just something to do with jmalloc, the allocator Rust uses, which has densely packed pools for small allocations.

> Can I assume that if a type only contains other POD types, then the layout will be the same as in C?

**No.** You pretty much can't assume anything about Rust's memory layout of types. This is intentionally not specified to allow for optimizations, such as field reordering. Even though *right now*, `repr(Rust)` matches `repr(C)` pretty closely, you can't assume that it will be like that forever.

Comment: Oh right, I can't believe that I didn't notice that. I guess I could use proc macros to dynamically implement some trait if the type has `#[repr(C)]`.

Comment: In particular, fields have been re-ordered for a bit recently, though that was temporarily backed out again: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/rolling-out-or-unrolling-struct-field-reorderings/4485